# How to configure Ubuntu for public kiosk use?

Tags: libraries, kiosk

My local library currently uses Windows with [Steadystate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState) to provide a locked-down, "stateless" PC.  It provides library patrons with access to a web browser, Office and a couple of other apps.  Once a patron logs off or their session times out, Steadystate wipes any changes they made to hard drive.

I'd like to do the same with Ubuntu:

- Provide access to Open/Libre Office
- Access to Chrome or Firefox.
- Be able to print to HP printers.
- Erase any changes made by the user after each user session and/or reboot.
- No access to the command line or any other unauthorized apps.

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/868/11175) provides a few answers but it's two years old so I'm wondering if there are newer/better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Great instructable on the topic here 
http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  The instructable is great for setting up Chromium but I also need to set up Openoffice, printer access and if possible, discard any state [if a user saved a document then that document should be erased before the next person uses the machine.]  Thanks.

Comment: Are all of the computers the same?

Comment: Yes, all the PC are the same.  But why does that matter?