# How to enable guest account automatic login?

Tags: guest-session, auto-login

I noticed in Ubuntu 11.10, that [finally there is possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631/starting-a-guest-session-from-the-login-screen) to log in with guest account already from log in screen. The last step is remaining - how to enable the guest account **automatically** log in, e.g. when computer starts? This would be very helpful for public computers, e.g. in libraries, schools, universities, student campus etc. This would be workaround for user account deep freeze feature, which is still missing from Ubuntu.

- [Solution for Ubuntu older than 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95405/how-to-enable-guest-account-automatic-login#answer-95410)
- [Solution for Ubuntu 13.10 and newer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95405/how-to-enable-guest-account-automatic-login#answer-465872)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with your favourite editor like `gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
  and under the section `[SeatDefaults]` add

```
allow-guest=true  
autologin-guest=true  
autologin-user-timeout=0  
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin  
user-session=ubuntu
```

Comment: @zeroconf: Please mark the question as answered since it worked

Answer (score 1):

For both **Ubuntu 14.10** and **Ubuntu 15.10** this is what worked for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

with the following content

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=true
```

What did not work for me under **Ubuntu 14.10** (Note: this was not tried under **Ubuntu 15.10**)...

1. Creating the `50-autoguest.conf` file in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`
2. Creating the `50-autoguest.conf` file in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`
3. Having the setting `allow-guest=true` in the settings file (that disabled Guest session altogether).

According to the LightDM wiki entry, the right place to put such modifications is in

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*
```

The following path is for the system-provided configuration only

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

The way I solved this was 'brute force'. I knew that I could set an auto-login using a regular account in Ubuntu 14.10 so I did that in Settings. Then I looked in the three locations I knew of where the auto-login preference was stored and, voila, the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` was created with a single entry for the account that was subject to auto login. Figuring that less is more I commented out the entry (prefixed `#`) and added only `autologin-guest=true` and it worked!

PS nano is my preferred command-line text editor. Its simple to use. That said, use whatever is your preferred text editor, e.g. `gksu gedit` if you prefer a GUI text editor.

Comment: @ale.com said: You must enable autologin for one user using graphical interface. ...or find where you need to change something else. I checked every /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d file without success.

Answer (score 0):

The lightdm config file location has changed in Ubuntu 14.04. To accomplish the same you need to create a new file */usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-auto-guest.conf*, for example by running

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-auto-guest.conf
```

and putting in this content:

```
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=true  
autologin-guest=true  
autologin-user-timeout=0  
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin  
user-session=ubuntu
```

Comment: I had to change the options in ``/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`` since this file has the highest priority and the settings were set there.

Answer (score -1):

Solution suggested by JumpingJuniper works for me too, but only following all of his path.

before adding

```
autologin-guest=true
```

to

```
sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

you *must* enable autologin for one user using graphical interface. ...or find where you need to change something else. I checked every /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d file without success