# Autologin Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop Session As Guest And Allow Web Browser

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, kiosk

How can you autologin session as Guest?

Bonus for if you explain how to limit the guest to only web browser functionality?  (and save no changes)

I see the thread here ([How to enable guest account automatic login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95405/how-to-enable-guest-account-automatic-login)), however the Ubuntu 14 file/settings appear to have changed.

Comment: Hi, I updated the original question with the information you need!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable guest account automatic login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95405/how-to-enable-guest-account-automatic-login)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same project using an Xubuntu base. I followed this link: http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS
 to get the initial setup running.

Once you have the session created, you may need to edit the kiosk user's ~/.dmrc file to read:

```
[Desktop]
Session=kiosk
```

substituting "kiosk" for the browser-only session name. I also created a file in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d similar to the existing 10-xubuntu.conf specifying my kiosk session. It took all of these to get the auto-login to work properly.

Also, if using Google Chrome or Chromium check out: http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start to see all of the policies you can hard-configure into Chrom{e,ium}. Since I'm setting this up for a school computer lab, I found several options that will allow us to curtail certain uses.

Hope this is helpful. I am by no means an uber linux user and I managed to get it that far. Lightdm can be a bit finicky at times. Google will find some good resources but be warned that on Xubuntu 14.04 the lightdm.conf documentation lives at /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz Several websites list other possibilities. Good luck.