# Ubuntu Kiosk with Libreoffice?

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, kiosk

I have been searching for about one week for a " Kiosk with firefox and Libreoffice " but unfortunately, I couldn't find it ! or my experience is not too much dealing with Ubuntu and Linus in general.

So, I want the user to be able to surf the Internet, print, copy files to his/her USB and of course open Libreoffice. Only that !

Can anybody help me with some simple steps, please?

Thank you,

Comment: Which Ubuntu version and flavor are you using ? You can configure the display manager to default auto login to the so-called "Guest session".  http://askubuntu.com/questions/95405/ddg#95410 That would make a good start to have a user with very minimal permissions. To enable access to only Firefox and Libreoffice and have printing and usb usage would require quite a bit more customization work. See also : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would personally suggest. I created an image once so that some friends could safely learn to use the terminal system, so I get what you need.

## Preparing your workstation

1. **Login as administrator and setup your system.** Go through every single piece of software and clear out the ones you don't want. Your user shouldn't have access to things he shouldn't be supposed to touch. They need to use the workstation for its intended purpose.
2. **Create a new user for your, well, users.** I would suggest using a terminal for the sake of simplicity. `sudo useradd sparky` should do the trick, adding the user named sparky. By this method, the user will not be in any groups by default. It won't be in the sudoers -- meaning it can't do anything but run user-level programs, such as whatever is installed and doesn't require root privilege. However, it is required to set passwords anyway.
3. **Set up the user to auto-login.** Now, you won't need to give away passwords for your users, and can simply tell your users to go use any computer. This, of course, is optional to you. It makes it easier for your users, though. P.S. Now might be a good time to make a backup, in case something goes wrong. Then you won't be stuck for the many hours of work I just put you through.

---

## Setting up auto login

> One of the reasons that Ubuntu systems are considered so secure is because they **require** passwords to install software or to configure the system. They also **require** passwords to login to the computer. If you want to **bypass the login password**, there is an **Auto Login function** you can set and use.

One of the reasons I love the terminal so much is that it makes complicated GUI tasks relatively quick. The GUI also makes complicated terminal tasks relatively quick. They each have their advantages.

Run the following to setup auto login.

`sudo mkdir /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf`

Copy and paste the following:

`[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=USERNAME`

That's all there is to it. But what do we do when the system suspends or goes into sleep mode?

1. Type gconf-editor in a terminal (Alt+Ctrl+T to call the terminal).
2. Go to apps/gnome-power-manager/locks
3. Check "use_screensaver_settings".
4. If still asked for password, you can (also in gconf-editor) go to desktop/gnome/lockdown and check: "disable_lock_screen"

And that should do it.

*Partially cited and edited from [the wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin).*

I hope this helps, as I put a lot of time into creating this. Should you need any assistance, please comment below! If I didn't answer your question, let me know so that I can help you figure it out.

Comment: Thank you very very much for this create explanation *Computer Looker*",

I almost did that, but I just wanted to create only an Ubuntu Kiosk with two programs only " Firefox and Libreoffice " 

Also, one more thing, the standard user can still launch the Terminal and execute the code " reboot " ?!

Once again, thank  you very much,

Comment: @Rebiwar Ah, yes. I forgot about that. You might want to add a line to ~/.bashrc for the user. `alias reboot="echo Ha, nice try!"` and it might be smart to add more lines for shutdown and other commands you shouldn't be able to access.

Comment: Oh, then after that, set the .bashrc file's ownership and permissions all to root so that users can't hack it.